# Retrieve/Update Salesforce Custom Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-object, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to retrieve/update the custom object which is on the connected sales cloud org.

For that, I'm used the Ampscript '**RetrieveSalesforceObjects()**' and '**UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()**' methods but the are not working,

```
Set @ParticipantId = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Participant', 'ParticipantID', 'Id', '=','aN4*******8j')

UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Event Participant',@ParticipantId,'Opt Out','true')
```

But when I tried these methods on the standard object to update/retrieve they are working fine.

I'm not getting, where exactly the problem is?
Is there anything related to the object permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the API names of the objects you want to retrieve/update. Hence your AmpScript calls should be:

```
Set @ParticipantId = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Participant__c', 'ParticipantID', 'Id', '=','aN4*******8j')
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Event_Participant__c',@ParticipantId,'Opt Out','true')
```

Please do verify the naming by logging into Sales Cloud, and viewing the object properties there.

Comment: Thank you @Lukas for the response, Yes I'll verify the names, also for a field name we need to use the API name?

Comment: Yes - the same applies for fields

Comment: Okay-I've tried by using the API names and it's worked. Thank you once again @Lukas